# Windows 10, cmd.exe The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I'm facing a strange kind of issue with my Windows 10 machine and couldn't find any solution so far.

Whenever, I open Windows 10 console or any console based application, it shows **The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.** message even before showing command prompt. Please see image attached below.

I have googled but couldn't find this kind of issue. I'm positive that I'll get some solution by genius people on this forum.

[image]

**Update:** Though I couldn't find any obvious reason of this problem but found a dirty solution and that is to delete current profile. After creating new account on same machine, I couldn't reproduce this issue. It appears that while upgrading my OS, something went wrong.

Comment: the funny thing is i can't even remember what command gives that error and when, but i've seen that message so many times. Just not immediately on starting cmd. It must be running some command. What is unusual is it's starting in `C:\\`  What method are you using to start cmd?

Comment: is cmd being started with some parameters e.g. cmd /c "sdfsd"  or cmd /k "sdfdsfs".  The only other alternative i'm aware of is if  you have a registry setting (in either of two locations mentioned in cmd /?) set with the location of a batch file, which is then running a command that is giving that error. I'd think cmd being launched with cmd /c or cmd /k followed by some command, is more likely.  And when did this "problem" start?

Comment: Yes. It event gives same error when I double click cmd.exe or it's shortcut.

Comment: look at the properties of the shortcut

Comment: and what if you're in cmd.exe and you run cmd<ENTER> do you get the message again, or no error message that second time?

Comment: Same behavior with cmd<enter>. I'm not suing any cmd flags.

Comment: @barlop. Please see my updated post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47234/discussion-between-barlop-and-saleem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was almost certainly caused by a corrupt AutoRun entry.

From the `cmd /?` help:

> If /D was NOT specified on the command line, then when CMD.EXE starts, it
>   looks for the following REG_SZ/REG_EXPAND_SZ registry variables, and if
>   either or both are present, they are executed first.
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
>
> ```
>    and/or
> ```
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

Since deleting the profile fixed the problem, it must have been an entry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.  Quite how that entry *got* there is more of a puzzle, but probably just some sort of glitch.

Comment: Though I have deleted profile and no way to verify but it definitely makes sense.  @barlop and Harry-johnston +1

Comment: you could add that since he also ruled out the cmd properties window..showing cmd /c outputting anything.. anyhow, it's very odd that he got anything pointing to a batch file  in the cmd.exe autorun  so it's really an unresolved mystery, that is now impossible to find out what it was.

Comment: harry, are you aware that you just posted in comment what i'd suggested to him 10 hours before you, besides the fact that he can't test whether this is correct anyway, since he deleted the profile, and it's not like people commonly get things into the autorun entry of cmd so for you to say it's almost certainly so is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @barlop: in my professional opinion, there's no other plausible explanation. (And I don't see what makes you think it was pointing to a batch file, as opposed to just containing a no-longer-valid path, or random nonsense?)

Comment: (I had assumed that if you wanted to post an answer you would have already done so; that's the convention on Stack Overflow, at any rate, and I'd have [posted the answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40192536/886887) had it been on-topic. Having bothered to follow the OP here, it didn't seem inappropriate to post my answer. However, if conventions are different here, I'll delete this if you want to post one instead. Or you could vote to close as no-longer-reproducible, though IMO there's a good chance someone else will have the same problem as it sounds to have been caused by the upgrade.)

Comment: maybe something silly there is plausible, it's a familiar looking error though I don't recall what command causes it - can you give an example of something in that registry entry that would cause that error?

Comment: @barlop: one possibility is anything that looks like a valid path but has an invalid character in anything but the filename, e.g., `c:\x*y\z`.  Also if there are too many colons for some reason, e.g., `c::`.  I haven't found a combination that works on Windows 7 but causes that particular error in Windows 10, but that may just be a failure of my imagination.